# Find Duplicate Customers

Tags: sql-server, query-refactor

Okay... I have a table that has customers:

```
-- Individual Table
* ID (Internal Unique ID)
* IndividualID (External Unique Individual Identifier)
* Last Name
* First Name
* Birth Date
* SSN
* ...
```

The issue is that sometimes a person gets multiple Individual ID's. Say the person doesn't provide a SSN for one Encounter, the last name changes, typo in birthday, etc. So you end up with the same person in the individual table multiple times:

```
1, Frost, Jack, 1/1/2000, 000-00-0008
2, Frost, Jack, 1/1/2000, 000-00-0003
3, Doe,   Jane, 1/1/2000, 000-00-0005
4, Doe,   Janet, 1/1/2000, 000-00-0005
5, Frost, Janet, 1/1/2000, 000-00-0005
```

Those are just some examples. The basic idea is that I need to find individuals that are potential matches, so that the right person can merge the individuals into a single account.

The particular query I'm currently on is on SS2008-SP1, but I have other queries on SS2005 through SS2012. Is there any way I can improve this?

Initially I had a single select statement (instead of 2 temp tables, 5 inserts and a select statement), but the "This or This or This or..." took many minutes and this takes ~10 seconds. Population of Customers is ~144k (`Select count(*) from Data`)

Current I'm using a simple attempt to try and match four parts: Last Name, First Name, DOB, SSN. If 3 or 4 of them match on different individuals, the need to be inspected closer to determine if they really are the same person.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#DATA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DATA;
GO

CREATE TABLE #DATA (
      EXTID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    , LNAME VARCHAR(30) NULL
    , FNAME VARCHAR(30) NULL
    , SSN VARCHAR(11) NULL
    , DOB VARCHAR(8) NULL
    )
GO

INSERT INTO #DATA
SELECT 
      EXTID = D1.EXTERNALID
    , LNAME = D1.LASTNAME
    , FNAME = D1.FIRSTNAME
    , SSN = CASE WHEN D1.SSN = '000-00-0000' THEN NULL ELSE D1.SSN END
    , DOB = convert(VARCHAR, D1.DOB, 112)
FROM Data D1
WHERE Type = 1 and STATUS = 1
GO

SELECT D1.*, [Splitter] = 'MATCH', D2.* 
FROM #Demo D1, #Demo D2 WHERE D1.ID > D2.ID
    AND (   D1.LNAME = D2.LNAME
        AND D1.FNAME = D2.FNAME
        AND D1.SSN   = D2.SSN
        AND D1.DOB   = D2.DOB)
        UNION
SELECT D1.*, 'LName', D2.* 
FROM #Demo D1, #Demo D2 WHERE D1.ID > D2.ID 
    AND (   D1.LNAME <> D2.LNAME
        AND D1.FNAME = D2.FNAME
        AND D1.SSN   = D2.SSN
        AND D1.DOB   = D2.DOB)
        UNION
SELECT D1.*, 'FName', D2.* 
FROM #Demo D1, #Demo D2 WHERE D1.ID > D2.ID
    AND (   D1.LNAME = D2.LNAME
        AND D1.FNAME <> D2.FNAME
        AND D1.SSN   = D2.SSN
        AND D1.DOB   = D2.DOB)
        UNION
SELECT D1.*, 'SSN  ', D2.* 
FROM #Demo D1, #Demo D2 WHERE D1.ID > D2.ID
    AND (   D1.LNAME = D2.LNAME
        AND D1.FNAME = D2.FNAME
        AND D1.SSN   <> D2.SSN
        AND D1.DOB   = D2.DOB)
        UNION
SELECT D1.*, 'DOB  ', D2.* 
FROM #Demo D1, #Demo D2 WHERE D1.ID > D2.ID
    AND (   D1.LNAME = D2.LNAME
        AND D1.FNAME = D2.FNAME
        AND D1.SSN   = D2.SSN
        AND D1.DOB   <> D2.DOB);
```

Edit to add Distinct Counts:

```
LName   FName   SSN DOB Count
36737   14539   115073  34284   144044
```

Edit: Cleaned up a bit to get rid of second temp table. Poking around the Estimated Execution plan, the above query - broken into 5 parts - uses hash map inner joins and takes about 10 seconds. My initial query, and other variations seem to use loop joins and is still chugging along at 10+ minutes.

Comment: Can you post the result of `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LNAME), COUNT(DISTINCT FNAME), COUNT(DISTINCT SSN), COUNT(DISTINCT DOB), COUNT(*) FROM Data` so we can see what are the most selective columns?

Comment: What do you mean "most selective"? The `ID` is unique. `IndividualID` is `Not Null`. Then you have Last/First/DOB/SSN - with associated typo's, empty/null, etc.

Comment: Well if you are interested in 3 out of 4 then you know that records matching that criteria must join on either `SSN` or `DOB` or both so you only need to two joins. It makes sense to do the most selective two columns.

Comment: (Couple edits on my previous post for clarity) Well my idea is to use 3 of the 4... but you can have 4 of 4 match and DOB/SSN/First/Last can all be wrong, change (as in  marriage/divorce), refused entry (Can refuse SSN)... So, in my mind, 5 possibilities: All match, different ID. 1 of 4 Doesn't match, different ID.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by matching them when no fields are the same so I've gone with the 3 out of 4 stated in the question.

Comment: Saw your edit to first comment. Added distinct counts.  Not sure where you see "No matches" (maybe a corrected typo on my part as well? lol), but it should be 3 or 4 matches.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment above. Where you said they "can all be wrong". I didn't see how they could be matched in that case!

Comment: I see it now. Yeah, I meant they can each be individually wrong (and possibly more, but I don't want to try and match on 2 of 4 at this stage, unless requested). Sorry about that, can't edit the comment

Comment: RE: "other variations" using nested loops does that include the query in my answer? If so what if you change both `JOIN` keywords to `INNER HASH JOIN`? If you don't have useful indexes I would have expected it to use hash or merge anyway though.

Answer (score 3):

To find rows where at least three out of four of those columns match you can use.

```
SELECT  D1.ID, D2.ID
FROM   DATA D1
       JOIN DATA D2
         ON D1.SSN = D2.SSN
            AND D1.ID > D2.ID
            AND 2 <= CASE
                       WHEN D1.FNAME = D2.FNAME THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END +
                     CASE
                       WHEN D1.LNAME = D2.LNAME THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END  +
                     CASE
                       WHEN D1.DOB = D2.DOB THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END
UNION ALL
SELECT D1.ID, D2.ID
FROM   DATA D1
       JOIN DATA D2
         ON D1.DOB = D2.DOB
         AND  D1.FNAME = D2.FNAME
         AND  D1.LNAME = D2.LNAME
         AND D1.SSN <> D2.SSN
         AND D1.ID > D2.ID
```

The top branch gets all rows where the `SSN` are the same and at least 2 out of the three other columns are the same. The join on `SSN` is likely to be pretty selective in itself.

That just leaves one other possible three column combination left which is dealt with by the second branch.

Both branches of the `UNION ALL` have an equi join so it should perform better than a join with some complicated `OR` condition.